# Rails 3: Get attributes between associated tables and how to call those in Model classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations, paperclip

I have 4 tables leagues, divisions, teams and coaches. The relationships between these tables described  as a league has many divisions, a division has many teams but only one coach for a team. I also want to query leagues from team through a division which associated to the team.

My current setup:

```
class League < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :divisions
  has_many :teams, :through => :divisions, :readonly => true
  has_many :coaches, :through => :teams, :readonly => true
end

class Division < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :league
  has_many :teams
end
```

I should mention right this point that I am using paperclip to upload team logos. However, when I wanted to change the storage path as: /public/assets/images/teams/[division_name]/:style/:basename.:extension, I don't know how to get the division name of the team to use for the path & url of file system storage.

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :division
  belongs_to :league
  belongs_to :stadium

  has_many :players
  has_one :coach

  has_attached_file :logo, :styles => { :large => "120x180>", :thumb => "100x100>", :tiny => "25x25>" },  
      :url => "/assets/images/teams/#{name}/:style/:basename.:extension",  
      :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/images/teams/#{name}/:style/:basename.:extension"

end

class Coach < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :division
  belongs_to :league
  belongs_to :stadium
  belongs_to :team
end
```

My problems so far:

1. Am I setting things correctly? It's very important that I want to query coaches and teams in a league or a division.
2. In Team class, I want to define a method(or whatever it called) which returns the division name of the team to include that division name to the url & path of storage configuration as above.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**UPDATE:** I tried to use `self.division.name` in team.rb class to get the name of division of the team:

```
has_attached_file :logo, :styles => { :large => "120x180>", :thumb => "100x100>", :tiny => "25x25>" },  
      :url => "/assets/images/teams/#{self.division.name}/:style/:basename.:extension",  
      :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/images/teams/#{self.division.name}/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

However, I am getting this error message:

```
`method_missing': undefined method `division' for #<Class:0x10c6a2900> (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but getting associated objects is quite easy:

```rb
# in team.rb
self.division.name #self is not required

# in division.rb
self.teams.first.name
```

But you don't need `has_many :teams, :through => :divisions` in your League class, since it's already linked to Division, which is linked to Team. You only use the "has_many through" when setting up many-to-many associations.

```rb
# in league.rb
self.divisions.first.teams.first
```

You can also use `asset_path('teams/my-name/some-file.jpg')` to get your images, but I guess that's only accessible in your views, helpers and controllers.

Comment: I tried to use `self.division.name` in my team.rb but it gave me error message: `method_missing': undefined method `division' for #<Class:0x10c6a2900> (NoMethodError)`

Comment: That's weird. Did you set up your migrations correctly? Where in the class are you trying to use the `division.name`?